# How to use apps-global with polymer's sampler-scaffold?

Tags: polymer

I am using sample-scaffold from https://github.com/Polymer/sampler-scaffold and define some globale variables using app-globals as described in https://www.polymer-project.org/docs/polymer/polymer.html#global

like

```
<app-globals myvar="value"></app-globals>
<sampler-scaffold>
  <core-item label="Page 1" url="page1.html"></core-item>
</sampler-scaffold>
```

page1.html contains also the app-globals without values.

```
<app-globals id="globals"></app-globals>
```

However, the globals element does not contain any values. Is there a way to define globals across iframes using app-globals?

Comment: Im not sure what are you using iframes for in this case?Do you have a jsbin or could you show the code you used to defined app-globals?

Comment: the sampler-scaffold uses iframes to switch between pages

Comment: @friedger is right, the sample-scaffold app uses iframes, here is a snapshot of a "working" implementation of it http://dev.cledwyn.com/boomerang-polymer-so26449196 with the issue that I also am experiencing.  Matching GitHub snapshot https://github.com/cledwyn/boomerang-polymer/tree/eb3f4b3499d6177cc01b47be5dd2d0e8e18b1d85

Comment: I created a plunker project to highlight just this issue http://plnkr.co/edit/lIzdY3?p=preview

Answer (score 0):

What about using the Polymer Element extensions? and inheritance to keep the interface of the app-globals object static?  My Plunker: http://embed.plnkr.co/uDPTVP/preview

**app-config.html**

```
<!-- per https://www.polymer-project.org/docs/polymer/polymer.html#extending-other-elements -->
<link rel="import" href="http://www.polymer-project.org/components/polymer/polymer.html">
<link rel="import" href="app-globals.html">
<polymer-element name="app-config" extends="app-globals">
  <script>
    Polymer({
      ready: function () {
        this.super();

        this.values.GloabalSettingsVal1 = "GDG FTW"

      }
    });
  </script>
</polymer-element>
```